# Area 51 allows you to see how much rep you have on a suspended site

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51, account-suspension

In Area 51, you can see the amount of rep you have in a suspended site.

For example, it just updated:

[image]

However, in my network flair I really only have 1302 total.

[image]

So, if we do the maths, I have 1112 rep on Arqade.

<sub>Ummmm that's wrong.</sub>

Could the rep list on Area 51 be changed to not include sites where I'm suspended?

Comment: But what exactly is wrong with that? I have about 5500 rep network wide, but it shows 6700 for me, since I earned 1200 in a failed gamification beta

Comment: @Zizouz212 create a sock, get suspended with the sock and try

Comment: So you'll create a sock because of this?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Nope, some Unidoggy got me suspended, not me

Comment: So let me get this clear: Your area 51 flair is showing your gaming rep (this is normal behaviour), and your network rep is different: that is your bug?

Comment: @Zizouz212 yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not erroneous behaviour: it's perfectly normal.

[Here's something I've proposed on Area 51](//area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88933/urban-planning). Look at the right: It shows that I have 6,778 rep at the time of this writing.

Now let's look at my network flair:

[image: profile for Zizouz212 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

At the time of this writing, it shows roughly 5,300 rep for my network-wide account.

#### So Why the Difference?

Area 51 includes the site rep for all sites that you have earned 200 rep on, whether your account is funky on one site, or another site is deleted altogether. Let's break my rep down:

- Open Source: 2647 rep
- Stack Overflow: 1829 rep
- Aviation: 536 rep
- Area 51: 289 rep

That's about 5300. I've earned rep on deleted sites as well, and then I have rep for this site too.

#### Why is it different?

Area 51 rep is supposed to be an indicator of the effort that you put into other sites. So it would be kind of unfair to just say that you didn't put effort into a site that was deleted for other reasons, or for anywhere that you are suspended. Area 51 takes all the rep that you have earned, whether you like it or not, to make your Area 51 specific flair. I have 6800 rep on Area 51 because of my contributions to failed betas, not because I'm special.

Comment: Perfectly written in a nice answer. Well done! +1

Comment: *not because I'm special.* Yes, you are...

Answer (score 0):

First I don't think it would be a problem. Although your reputation on suspended sites are fixed to 1, it doesn't mean that your original reputation would be an undisclosed thing.

You can any time check your *real* (unsuspended) reputation on the http://anything.stackexchange.com/reputation link.